# NoMethodError in Clients#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller, nomethoderror

So I'm getting this error in one of my views and it seems to have to do with the way client is being initialized in the controller, here's the code for my Client model and controller:

Model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :visits
    has_many :exchanges, through: :visits
```

Controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @clients = Client.all
    end


    # GET /clients/new
    def new
        @client = Client.new
    end

   # POST /clients
   # POST /clients.json
   def create
        @client = Client.new(client_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @client.save
              format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @client }
          else
              format.html { render action: 'new' }
              format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
       end
   end

  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1.json
  def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @client.update(client_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
     end
  end

  # DELETE /clients/1
  # DELETE /clients/1.json
  def destroy
      @client.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to clients_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_client
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def client_params
      #hidden for security
  end
end
```

So the error goes off at line 1 for my client form when it calls @client and says "undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Client:Class"  Really could use some help as I have no idea what is going on, thanks.

Error Stack:

```
Started GET "/clients/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-06 14:05:48 -0400
Processing by ClientsController#new as HTML
Rendered clients/_form.html.erb (62.2ms)
Rendered clients/new.html.erb within layouts/application (65.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 68ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Client:Class):
1: <%= simple_form_for(@client) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @client.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>
app/views/clients/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_clients__form_html_erb___2200324505640086965_70348410359440'
app/views/clients/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_clients_new_html_erb___3059029162300151807_70348376263300'


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (12.8ms)
```

Comment: Please post full error stack.
Please also post your `show` template and `form` partial.

Comment: ruby definition for `class` is with lowercase(you wrote as `Class`), but problem would be other. Paste full error stack as wrote Marek.

Comment: sorry just copied it wrong my class is spelled with a lowercase c already

Comment: @nbyron Can you share the view code of `new.html.erb`?

Comment: @KirtiThorat sure all it has is: <h1>New client</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', clients_path %>  and the error is happening on like 1 of the rendered form which can be seen above.

Comment: @nbyron Can you share ApplicationController class. Also, in your Client model, is that all what you have in the question or you have any more code in it?

Comment: @KirtiThorat my client model has some validations in it as well and my application controller only has:  

    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception  
    end

Comment: Can you try in your rails console this simple piece of code: "c=Class.new", add same data "c.column1, c.column2=data1,data2", save "c.save" and see what happens?

Comment: it says the column1 and column2 and their data are undefined and that save is not a defined method